# Automatically connect to Cellular Network (LTE)

Tags: ios-xe, lte

I am working on implementing a LTE configuration on IOS-XE (ISR1000) devices. Issue we have is, that we have to "genereate" some traffic in order for the cellular interface to initiate a connection. This it the WAN interface configuration:

```
interface Cellular0/2/0
 description WAN
 ip vrf forwarding DSL
 ip address negotiated
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip nat outside
 zone-member security WAN
 dialer in-band
 dialer idle-timeout 0
 dialer watch-group 2
 dialer-group 2
 ipv6 enable
 pulse-time 1
 ip virtual-reassembly
end
```

If we have a IP SLA active on the router, that starts up and tries to connect to the Internet, then the LTE connection is getting initialized as well. We can see that the IP SLA is the reason to initiate the connection:

```
roTST02#show dialer                  
Ce0/2/0 - dialer type = DIALER CWAN
Idle timer (never), Fast idle timer (20 secs)
Wait for carrier (30 secs), Re-enable (15 secs)
Dialer state is data link layer up
Dial reason: ip (s=172.20.20.1, d=8.8.8.8)
Time until disconnect never
Current call connected 00:45:41
Connected to lte
```

If we delete the IP SLA configuration, the router will only start to connect to the internet, once a client from the LAN tries to connect to it. Otherwise it just stays offline.

I tried to issue a "dialer persistent" on the cellular interface, but this command is not supported.

```
roTST02(config)#interface cellular 0/2/0
roTST02(config-if)#dialer per?
% Unrecognized command
roTST02(config-if)#dialer persistent
                           ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

Question: how can i initiate a LTE connection after a reboot wihtout the workaround of generating some traffic first?

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: Tested on 16.12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't run a version that supports the `dialer persistent` command, you will have to generate some traffic to get the dialer to fire.

Comment: I have seen that done with an EEM script.

Comment: EEM script would be a solution, as it can be run run X seconds after the router has been rebooted. IP SLA would run always in the background. I thought maybe there is a way to have a configration on the interface that would connect wihtout implementing a workaround.

Comment: IP SLA can run for a limited time, say 1 minute.